Is pride a good or a bad things?
There is the pride one can have for succeeding in something that requires a lot of work. I am not talking about this here.
Is the pride that can make a person angry, when its dignity is hurt a good thing? Should we see it as a defense mechanism? or more as a weakness, and a missed opportunity to avoid a conflict?
also, I am very open if you know any paper/study/philosopher that talked about this.

@AlexJRButterfly Possibly it is easier to answer after you have focused your post by clarifying your definition of pride and of dignity. I don't see how you relate the two concepts. Thanks.

Thank you for your comment.
I relate the two concepts very closely unless I completely misunderstand the concept of dignity. If you are hurt by pride, isn't your dignity also being hurt? But now that you ask, I am not sure I can understand the difference. Thank you for making me realise it!

Pride is a function of ego in its interaction with society. When we accomplish or contribute different things, we have an expectation that others will reward or commend us for it. This is part of how societies function. Societies require reciprocity to exist — cooperation, exchange, forbearance, etc are essential components — and such forms of regard are signals from others that we are established within a society and can reap its benefits. When we are denied such, it is an implied threat to our wellbeing; a signal that someone disproves of our membership in society. 'Hurt pride' in its simplest sense means that we are not having our own expectations met because we are not performing to society's expectations: a generally non-problematic sign that we should review our efforts.
This can turn toxic when our expectations are divorced from our actual accomplishments and contributions, as though society owes us something in a non-reciprocal manner. That kind of hurt pride can be nasty and difficult to root out.
Dignity is a form of pride granted by all members of society to each of its members. It's a basic level of recognition granted solely by virtue of being a member of that society. There are times when hurt dignity is perfectly valid (as in unwarranted abuse), and times when dignity boils down to toxic entitlement.
